# Symfony 3.x - Many to many extra field form collection

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, symfony-forms

I'll try to be as short as possible.

**Case story:**

I have one entity to handle let's say "Hotel Rooms", one entity to handle "Room's spec" and a middle entity "Room has spec". This is a many to many transformed in 2xOneToMany.

**What i would need:**

When i build the form for the "Hotel room" build a list of checkboxes with the full list of "Room's specs".
Obviously i would need to have any existing "room spec" checked if the room actually have it (a row inside the middle entity table). The initial case would be to have all the "Room's spec" list unchecked.

**My options:**

1. Remove the intermediate entity since it's actually just a true/false row, but then i would need to make symfony understand that if no row in the M-M relationship exist, then the room doesn't have that spec, on the other hand if the row exist the room has the spec. What i actually fear is that in the near future my customer would need to have some numbers, for example how many mirror the room has
2. Make all this thing become a standard Symfony form collection using the allow_add option, making all the rows to be created manually from the user. Not the best UX ever but it could be a solution
3. Manually handle the list creation, editing, removing inside the controller, tedious work

**Code:**

What's the correct and best way (if it exist) to write the Form builder?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If anyone will ever land here the solution was quite straightforward, all you need to do is to be sure you declared link between room and specs with a ManyToMany, then inside the room form you can use an EntityType and just set the 'expanded' option to TRUE

Comment: So you removed the intermediate entity and went for `ManyToMany` instead of 2 times `OneToMany`?

Comment: @TheFrost yes that's what nailed it for me :)